# Emitting a custom event within a function in methods object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling, vuejs2, vue-component

When a v-on:click event is triggered on my button, I would like to run a function within my methods object inside my Vue component. Unfortunately, since I need to emit a custom event, I get the following error in my console: $emit is not defined.

**How do I emit a custom event within a function in my methods object?**

**The button in my template**

```
<button class="edit-recipe-modal-btn" v-on:click="updateRecipeClicked">Save Edits</button>
```

**My methods object containing code to emit a custom event**

```
methods: {
  updateRecipeClicked() {
    $emit('update-recipe-clicked', newRecipe);
    // some other code will be written here
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `this`

```
methods: {
  updateRecipeClicked() {
  this.$emit('update-recipe-clicked', this.newRecipe );
  // some other code will be written here
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked; however, I realised I also needed to change newRecipe to this.newRecipe. If you can edit this part of your solution I will mark your solution as correct :) Also, seems a little weird I need the keyword "this" on an emit function, can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: What you actually trying to do here is, dispatching an event to the parent component of the method. So, for that, you need `this` keyword. See the documentation and you will understand. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events